# Caching images using PHP Image Cache

Tags: php, image, caching, gd

I am using this image caching library (http://nielse63.github.io/php-image-cache/) to cache images I am getting using the OMBD API (http://omdbapi.com/).

This is my setup:

```
    $imagecache  = new ImageCache();
    $imagecache->cached_image_directory = '/img/cache/';
    $imagecache->cached_image_url = '/img/cache';
    $cached_src_two = $imagecache->cache( 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/eYVZP9CibJg1fyZnZahfFIYqfPr.jpg' );
    echo 'Original file size: ' . filesize($imagecache->image_src) . ' bytes<br>';
    echo 'PHPImageCach-ified file size: ' . filesize($imagecache->cached_filename) . ' bytes<br>';
    echo 'Total image size reduction: ' . (((filesize($imagecache->image_src) - filesize($imagecache->cached_filename)) / filesize($imagecache->image_src))*100) . '%';
    echo '<img src="'.$cached_src_two.'" alt="">';
```

I am not getting any errors. But something weird is going on I can't understand. It is saving a local copy of the image in `$imagecache->cached_image_directory` - this is not compressed or cached. Then it is creating another file in the `img` directory.

I assume this is the cached file, but I am unable to open it to check. The cached filename looks like: `eYVZP9CibJg1fyZnZahfFIYqfPr.jpg.jpeg`

Note the `jpg.jpeg`. Even fixing the file extension does not work. I can't find anything useful in the documentation. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I`m guessing here,but it might be that imagecache need the files saved to the local disk before.